# Select two columns from the sqlite which got unique column and ordered by Date, Time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables which got same columns, examples

```
TableA

ID, Image, Date ,  Time
0 , 0    , 12/03,  12:33
0 , 1    , 12/03,  12:34
1 , 2    , 12/03,  12:34
1 , 3    , 12/03,  12:35

TableB

ID, Image, Date ,  Time
0 , 4    , 12/03,  12:33
0 , 5    , 12/03,  12:35
2 , 6    , 12/03,  12:34
2 , 7    , 12/03,  12:35
```

The results I need are

```
ID, Image, Date ,  Time
0 , 5    , 12/03,  12:35
1 , 3    , 12/03,  12:35
2 , 7    , 12/03,  12:35
```

This is easy to be done if it was one table

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Image FROM TableA GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC LIMIT 5
```

But how could I select from two tables?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  You are ordering by `time` in an aggregation query an not selecting it.

Comment: Why two similar tables instead of common table?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff You are right, this command did not order the data properly, figuring how to fix it

Comment: @jarlh Because the data are come from different sources and do not need to know each other long time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`.  This returns the most recent image from the two tables combined for each `id`:

```
with ab as (
      select a.* from TableA a union all
      select b.* from TableB b
     )
SELECT ID, Image
FROM (SELECT ab.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ab
     ) ab
WHERE seqnum = 1;
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is the rows with the latest date and time (as your expected results):

```
with cte as (
  select * from Tablea
  union all
  select * from Tableb
)
select * from cte
where Date || Time = (select max(Date || Time) from cte)
order by id
```

I assume the dates are always in the format `MM/YY` and the times `hh:mm`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMzWT5jz7Ph6aBEzyVjyfn/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Image | Date  | Time  |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 0   | 5     | 12/03 | 12:35 |
| 1   | 3     | 12/03 | 12:35 |
| 2   | 7     | 12/03 | 12:35 |
```